# How can I provide access to different user over the Power BI report embedded into SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, error, powerbi

I have a power bi report and is embedded to SharePoint Online page. Now, users other than me if trying to open the SharePoint page, unable to view the Report over the page and getting below error:

> It looks like you don't have access to this report
> Ask the report owner to share it with you

So, please guide me with steps on how to provide access to users for the report in power bi service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below Microsoft official documentation for sharing Power BI reports with other users:

[Share Power BI reports and dashboards with coworkers and others](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-share-dashboards?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

**Prerequisites**:

- You need a [Power BI Pro or Premium Per User (PPU) license](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/fundamentals/service-features-license-type?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224), whether you share content inside or outside your organization.
- Your recipients also need Power BI Pro or Premium Per User (PPU) licenses, unless the content is in a [Premium capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-what-is?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

---

1. Go to [Power BI portal](https://app.powerbi.com?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).
2. Select the workspace where you have published your Power BI report.
3. You will see the "Share" option in listing under workspace:

   [image]

---

Also, when you open a report from Power BI service portal, you will see the "Share" option like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all users have license to access the Power BI. You need to give user access rights in both places

1. to SharePoint site/Page
2. In PowerBI report as well.

You could use Azure AD group to manage that and then add user only to Azure AD group and then grant the group access in both places.

Comment: I think users already have access to the SharePoint site page. They need access on the Power BI report/dashboard as they are seeing the error message on the page.